# How do I update the sitemap in D7?

Tags: 7, xml-sitemap

I want to exclude some pages from the sitemap.

I go to these pages/nodes, edit them, then go to the XML sitemap tab and set it to 'Exclude'.

I then save and clear cache.

But when I look at my sitemap.xml file nothing is changed - the page URLs are still present.

How do I remove them?

Answer (score 1):

The XML Sitemap module doesn't rebuild sitemaps on every node save/load; also, it's not cached like other artifacts in Drupal.

The module tracks XML Sitemap links and they are added/removed upon cron runs. So you'll need to run cron to rebuild your sitemap files.

You can also follow some of the steps in the [*Setting up your site map (7.x)*](https://www.drupal.org/node/2364991) documentation:

> 8. Under "Inclusion" change "Excluded" to become "Included"
> 9. To add pages linked from menus to the sitemap, visit the edit page for each menu whose items should be included (this would usually
>      include the Main menu). Open the XML sitemap fieldset, and similarly
>      change "Excluded" to "Included". Hit Save.
> 10. Once that is all complete, go to Configurations --> Search and Metadata --> XML Sitemap
> 11. Click on the Rebuild Links tab in the upper right
> 12. Click on "Rebuild sitemap" even if the message says that you do not need to.
> 13. Now you're taken back to the config page which shows you the link to your xmlsitemap which you can click and confirm that pages have
>       been added